# paypal IPN - how to know when money has moved?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a basic HTML form to call PayPal (webscr) and I am successfully getting IPN callbacks.

There is plenty of documentation about the contents of each individual variable that can be returned in an IPN.   There is something important missing, or else I have missed it:

What paypal transaction types and payment statuses reflect actual changes in my account balance?   For example, a "Completed" status certainly does, and a "Pending" status certainly does not.

However, there appear to be five or six relevant transaction types and eleven different payment statuses possible.   Other than trying all 55 or 66 combinations in the IPN simulator, is there any document that clearly shows for which ones I should accumulate the mc_gross amount?

Or to put it another way, some IPN messages are just "in case I need to know", and some mean "money has changed hands; adjust your accounts accordingly".    It's not clear to me which combinations of transaction type and payment status indicate the latter.

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: If you read the [description of each txn_type](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z) it's pretty clear which ones move money and which ones don't.

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example txn_type="adjustment" means "A dispute has been resolved and closed".   Did money move? 

I studied that page for a couple days before asking here.   Of course one can draw some reasonable inferences about which ones actually indicate transferred funds.  Where financial transactions are involved one cannot rely on reasonable inferences; Is there no PayPal document that answers my question?  (I could not find one).

Comment: I *think* I found an answer to the example in my previous reply on the developer help pages, but I also found some obviously out-of-date documentation, also on paypal's site.   Not clear which I can trust. 

It seems to me that a company that handles over $300M each day could afford to create documentation that is correct, complete and (most important) unambiguous.